# Diccionario Python llamar keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, diccionarios

No puedo llamar a mi valor de la key name. Me da error: `string indices must be integers, not str`. Necesito si o si usar el for pero no entiendo porque me da ese error

```
diccionario = {
    "inventorysources":(
        {
            'name': 'DK $ 2 |',
            'device': 'desktop',
            'cost':2,
            'floor':2.5,
            'publisher':"5a01e576becbf9000255f29c"
        }
    )
}

for inv in diccionario["inventorysources"]:
    name = inv['name']
    print name
```

Answer (score 3):

Cuando ejecutas el bucle `for`, estás iterando a través de los elementos del diccionario `inventorysources`, siendo `name` uno de esos elementos. O lo que es lo mismo, `inv` va a tener en algún momento el valor de `name`.

Intuyo que tu equivocación es que querías que `inventorysources` fuera una tupla de diccionarios. Date cuenta que ahora mismo, tal como está, no es una *(mono)tupla*, los paréntesis sobran.

Si fuera una monotupla no tendrías problemas:

```
diccionario = {
    "inventorysources":(
        {
            'name': 'DK $ 2 |',
            'device': 'desktop',
            'cost':2,
            'floor':2.5,
            'publisher':"5a01e576becbf9000255f29c"
        }
    ,)
}
```

Fíjate en la coma de la penúltima línea que convierte el item en monotupla.

Answer (score 1):

```python
diccionario = {
    "inventorysources":(
        {
            'name': 'DK $ 2 |',
            'device': 'desktop',
            'cost':2,
            'floor':2.5,
            'publisher':"5a01e576becbf9000255f29c"
        }
    )
}
for inv in diccionario:
    name = diccionario[inv]
    print (name)
```

Espero te funcione a como lo necesitas, así mandas a llamar al diccionario completo y lo imprimes.

También puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
for key in diccionario:
  print (key, ":", diccionario[key],'\n')
```